# How do I create an ImageMap in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am creating a Login Page in ExtJS 3.4.  It has an image and I would like to create an image map so when the user clicks on piece of an image, it goes to an external site.

Here is the code:

```
var headerImage = new Ext.BoxComponent(
    { autoEl:
        { 
            tag: 'img',
            src: AVRMS.ROOT_CONTEXT + "/ssl/images/LoginHeader.png"
        } });

    var loginButton = {
        xtype: 'compositefield',
        id: 'cmpLogin',
        combineErrors: false,
        height: 50,
        items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                    value: ''
                },
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Login',
            listeners: {
                click: function () {
                    loginUser();
                }
            }
        }]
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
var imageMap = "<map name='imgMap'><area shape='rect' coords='23,185,233,241' href='http://www.ohio.gov' /><area shape='circle' coords='670,201,50' href='" + manageAccount + "' /></map>";
var imageUrl = "<img src='" + AVRMS.ROOT_CONTEXT + "/ssl/images/LoginHeader.png" + "' usemap='#imgMap' />";

var headerImage = new Ext.Panel(
    { items: [
        {
            html: imageMap + imageUrl
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar and I used this ExtJS library: http://code.google.com/p/imgmap/ . You can find very nice and useful examples. Enjoy!

Comment: How do I use that with ExtJS?

Comment: @GregFinzer You go here http://code.google.com/p/imgmap/downloads/list  download `imgmap_2.2_108.zip` and extract it in your computer... then it has an example folder with multiple example subfolders for different plugins: one of them is ExtJS and is named `example_extjs_files`

Comment: The example uses ExtJS 2.2 if I remember correctly but it works very smoolty with ExtJS 3.4 also

Comment: I just tried it.  I don't need an editor to create an image map but the ability to use the image map in ExtJS.

Comment: Here is what I need to use in ExtJS:   <map id="imgmap2009210102921" name="imgmap2009210102921">
  <area shape="rect" alt="Wikipedia" title="Wikipedia" coords="149,74,291,175" href="www.google.com" />
 </map>